# Pandas: Expand column containing list into new column variables with cells representing count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I started by data set with individual click data. I have aggregated the data in a yearly fashion to build a time series. But one of the problem I ran is aggregating click's source (example where click came from). As a result of that after aggregating I have following data frame.

```
    year  month  clickSource
0   2010    01  google, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook
1   2010    02  facebook, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook
2   2010    03  yahoo, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook
3   2010    04  google, yahoo, google, twitter, facebook, facebook
4   2010    05  facebook, yahoo, google, google, facebook, facebook
5   2010    06  twitter, yahoo, google, twitter, facebook, google
```

I want to introduce column to each unique item in the `clickSource` column's along with the count example:

```
    year  month  google  yahoo  facebook  twitter
0   2010    01    3       1         2       0
1   2010    02    2       1         3       0   
2   2010    03    2       2         2       0 
...
```

Initially my column was a string object so I covert it to list as fallows:

```
temp['clickSource'] = temp['clickSource'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

Then I made a series:

```
col_names = temp['clickSource'].apply(pd.Series)
```

But this created a column for every item in the list instead once per item (obviously because I didn't tell it to count etc). How to I obtain what I explained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a dataframe with the source column split and spread across multiple columns:

```
df = temp.clickSource.str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Extract the counters of elements in that dataframe, and get duplicate column names:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

Group the result along the column axis and sum the results:

```
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()
df 
   facebook  google  twitter  yahoo
0         2       3        0      1
1         3       2        0      1
2         2       2        0      2
3         2       2        1      1
4         3       2        0      1
5         1       2        2      1
```

Merge the two resulting dataframes:

```
pd.concat([temp, df], axis=1)
Out[48]: 
   year  month  facebook  google  twitter  yahoo
0  2010      1         2       3        0      1
1  2010      2         3       2        0      1
2  2010      3         2       2        0      2
3  2010      4         2       2        1      1
4  2010      5         3       2        0      1
5  2010      6         1       2        2      1
```

Comment: looks like you have the winning answer. For some reason other two methods didn't aggregate. Instead they all expanded the columns without aggregation. Not sure why.

Answer (score 4):

```
df.set_index(['year', 'month']).clickSource.str.split(', ') \
    .apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: `apply(pd.value_counts)` does the magic by magically merging the various indexes into columns indices. Do you have anything to point out in the documentation of apply or related that justify that, or it's pure (past or) present trial and success? I didn't engage to give it a try this way as I would not expect apply to do that magical here. Any insight welcome

Comment: @boud, by trial I know that `pd.value_counts` takes a list and returns a series with unique values in the index and counts as the values.  Apply across a series with a function that returns a series is exactly what does that magic.  Even further, I'm pretty sure (though, I haven't gone to look) that `pd.value_counts` uses `np.unique(x, return_counts=True)` which returns a tuple of unique values and value counts.

Comment: @Boud had a winning answer. For some reason this didn't work. It expanded the column and when I looked at the end results it had multiple google, facebook columns.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis good to know. I circle back and try to fix it. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df, 
          df.clickSource.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(', ')).value_counts()).fillna(0)], 
          axis = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very elegant answer but as I mentioned in other answers final data frame had multiple `google, facebook` instead of having one to represent all google etc. I know in your answer it really works not sure what it didn't work. @Boud's answer worked.